# Nested Selection in Odoo 9.0

Tags: odoo

I'm new at Odoo developing, and I have to create a form with nested selectors, like `Country>state>city`, where when I pick the first one the second selector gets updated just with the stats for the country, and then repeat the same process with the third selector. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm tempted to give you a straight code answer. but if you do some research and put some effort, you should be able to do this on your own. You need three models (If you don't want to re-use odoo's own) related with `Many2one` and then domain filters on these three fields that are triggered by `api.onchange`. When you have a real question with implementing this, we'll be here to help you out :)

Comment: Thanks @danidee your comment gives me the extra info what I needed